# Trying to find a cell based on value then using the cell (column) location as part of my formula

Tags: vba, excel

So i have this big spreadsheet, the columns and rows are always changing.
What i want to do is find a cell based on it's value, then paste a formula underneath it.  In this case the value is part of a header thus always in the same row.

[image: Sample Data]

The problem is that i'm trying to sum all the values to the left of the cell.  I know which cell to start from but not the cell that it ends at.  here's my code what am i doing wrong?

```
Sub OutageManagement()

Dim rngX As Range

Set rngX = Worksheets("WDCap").Range("13:13").Find("MI WD Cap. Reduction",   lookat:=xlPart)

rngX.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(G15:" & rngX.Column & "15)"

 End Sub
```

Bonus points if you can help me with the next step

basically there's another header i need to find thats to the right of my first header, then enter another formula which is adding the sums from where the firsts header was + 3 columns and to the column where the new header is -1.

Sorry if i'm not making sense, bulot of things that doesn't make sense today.

**For those interested this is the code i ended up using**

```
Sub WDOutageManagement()
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim vCell1, vCell2
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   
    Set rngX = Worksheets("WDCap").Range("13:13").Find("MI WD Cap. Reduction", lookat:=xlPart)
        'MI
    vCell1 = Replace(rngX.Offset(2, -1).Address, "$", "")
    rngX.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUM(G15:" & vCell1 & ")"
    Range(rngX.Offset(2, 0), rngX.Offset(LastRow - 13, 0)).FillDown  
    'LM
    vCell1 = Replace(rngX.Offset(2, 5).Address, "$", "")
    Set rngX = Worksheets("WDCap").Range("13:13").Find("LM WD Cap. Reduction", lookat:=xlPart)
    vCell2 = Replace(rngX.Offset(2, -1).Address, "$", "")
    rngX.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & vCell1 & ":" & vCell2 & ")"
    Range(rngX.Offset(2, 0), rngX.Offset(LastRow - 13, 0)).FillDown
    End Sub
```

Comment: I posted an answer for your first inquiry and for your 2nd inquiry, it will be better if you put a screenshot of a sample data you want to work on.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/MTTa4

Hi Rowen, thanks for your help.

So basically rngx gets me to AQ13, then i need to paste the formula in AQ15, then drag the formula to the last row.  

So that's the first part. with your help i think i got that.

The 2nd part is that to the right of AQ 13, i need to do the same thing.  the header will be unique but the number of columns in between will be different.  the tricky part i'm faced with is the sum part.  how do i only pick up the range that's to the right of my first formula

Comment: actually i am running into a problem
rngx should be AQ13.  using the formula above i get J

Comment: I updated my code to correctly set the columns, and I added the code for your 2nd inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really get a sum of values in a cell if that cell is part of your `=SUM()` formula so I changed the formula to get the sum of values from column G to 1 column to the left of the current column.

Then it looks for the second header and gets the sum of values 1 cell to the right of the first sum of values to 1 cell to the left of the column of the second header on row 15.

You can start working on this code:

```
Sub OutageManagement()

    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim vCell1, vCell2

    Set rngX = Worksheets("WDCap").Range("13:13").Find("MI WD Cap. Reduction", lookat:=xlPart)

    vCell1 = Replace(rngX.Offset(2, -1).Address, "$", "")

    rngX.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUM(G15:" & vCell1 & ")"

    vCell1 = Replace(rngX.Offset(2, 1).Address, "$", "")

    Set rngX = Worksheets("WDCap").Range("13:13").Find("Another Header", lookat:=xlPart)

    vCell2 = Replace(rngX.Offset(2, -1).Address, "$", "")

    rngX.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & vCell1 & ":" & vCell2 & ")"

End Sub
```

Here's some mock data I made. From G15 to AP15, I put 1. From AR15 to BR15, I put 2.

[image]

And here's after running the macro showing the sum of 1s, which is 36, and the sum of 2s, which is 54.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, just got back from vacation.  This works great.   thank you sir.

Comment: FYI i added the code i ended up using to the original post.  thanks again